# select drop down's - target default title

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a select drop down with the default title `Country` as grey. 
However the grey only shows up when you click into the field. 
How can i have the visible field with the default as grey so that it matches other fields? 
[image]

```
.form_0{color:#777;}

<select value='country' id='country' name='Country'>
    <option class='country' disabled='disabled' selected='selected' class='form_0'>Country</option>
    <option class='country'>Brazil</option>
    <option class='country'>China</option>
    <option class='country'>India</option>
    <option class='country'>Spain</option>
    <option class='country'>USA</option>
    <option class='country'>Japan</option>
    <option class='country'>Russia</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe :

```
$("#country").on('change', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("empty", this.value == "0");
}).change();​
```

You'll need to add values to your select, and change it a little bit:

```
<select id='country' name='Country'>
    <option value="0" class='country' selected='selected'>Country</option>
    <option value="1" class='country'>Brazil</option>
    <option value="2" class='country'>China</option>
    <option value="3" class='country'>India</option>
    <option value="4" class='country'>Spain</option>
    <option value="5" class='country'>USA</option>
    <option value="6" class='country'>Japan</option>
    <option value="7" class='country'>Russia</option>
</select>​
```

As a sidenote, you can't define class twice, you define two classes but doing:

```
<option class='country form_0'></option>
```

in the same decleration seperated by a space, two class declerations won't work.

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/UqCng/2/)

Answer (score 2):

check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWcrv/)

**HTML**

```
<select value='country' id='country' name='Country' style='color:#777'>
 <option  disabled='disabled' selected='selected' class='form_0'>Country</option>
   <option class='country'>Brazil</option>
   <option class='country'>China</option>
   <option class='country'>India</option>
   <option class='country'>Spain</option>
   <option class='country'>USA</option>
   <option class='country'>Japan</option>
   <option class='country'>Russia</option>
</select>​
```

**css**

```
.form_0{color:#777;}
.country{color:black}
```

​

**jquery**

```
$('#country').change(function(){
    $(this).css('color','black') ;
 });
```

​